# How to declare website URL for email confirmation?

Tags: php, mail-server

My site URL is `http://www.qadenza.site90.com`
Inside php configuration file, I have a line for declaring the site's URL. So I wrote

```
DEFINE('WEBSITE_URL', 'http://www.qadenza.site90.com');
```

But smtp (i.e. mail) server does not send me a confirmation mail after registering a new user.
New user is properly added to database.
Bacause my members area scripts are inside a folder `Members` i tried:

```
DEFINE('WEBSITE_URL', 'http://www.qadenza.site90.com/Members');
```

Without result.

Then i wrote:

```
DEFINE('WEBSITE_URL', 'http://localhost');
```

Confirmation mail arrived, but with wrong activation link (localhost...)
What should I write as website URL ?

Comment: and why you're just not using your simple website address, why you want to have a constant for that? it will be always the same, so!?

Comment: @behz4d, excuse me, I don't understand you. website address is a constant, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, it is! but while you're using it for sending emails, is it necessary to define a constant for that? I mean why don't you just use your activation link with the real address as a simple string.

Comment: @behz4d, registered user should click on the link in confirmation mail, to activate it's account. But that link is wrong, or activation mail doesn't arrive. Please, write an example of your solution.

Comment: I just mean that in the activation link, instead if echo WEBSITE_URL DO: echo "http://www.qadenza.site90.com"!

Comment: @behz4d, but activation link sends mail server, not me. This is a link with encrypted data, very long, i'm sure you saw it already during registering on a site.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20772/discussion-between-behz4d-and-alegro)